# How do I delete entire duplicate row if first value is repeated in text file java

Tags: java, list

I'm trying to delete entire duplicate row if first value is repeated in textfile using java then store the textfile records into ArrayList

My Text file

```
123456,greenwitch street,near dominos store,Opp sandwitch company,Neyork,US,876890
123480,Postwitch street,near KFC store,Opp masala company,Newyork,US,876891
123456,Newyork street,near 100th avenue,King master company,Texas,US,10005
```

In above file first ,3rd line starting word is same and other values are different and want to delete entire 3rd row.

I tried below code to remove duplicates after storing the values into BufferedReader but not working

```
List<String> uniqueList = sourceList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Instead of distinct() use filter() . Although, you may need to use a stateful predicate, which remembers the IDs which it has already crossed: https://www.baeldung.com/java-streams-distinct-by

Answer (score 0):

A plain and straightforward solution would be to generate a `Map` using the numeric index at the beginning of the line as a Key, and the line itself as a Value.

That how it might be implemented using Collector [`toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)):

```
List<String> sourceList = List.of(
    "123456,greenwitch street,near dominos store,Opp sandwitch company,Neyork,US,876890",
    "123480,Postwitch street,near KFC store,Opp masala company,Newyork,US,876891",
    "123456,Newyork street,near 100th avenue,King master company,Texas,US,10005"
);
        
List<String> uniqueList = sourceList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        str -> str.substring(0, str.indexOf(',')), // keyMapper - generating a Key
        Function.identity(),   // valueMapper - creating a Value
        (left, right) -> left  // mergeFunction - resolving duplicates
    ))
    .values().stream().toList();
```

But depending on what you're going to do with these strings further, it might make sense to introduce a class, like `Company`. Parse the string into it's instances and operate with them.

Consider the following domain class, for conciseness I'll make use of the Lombok's annotations `@Getter` and `@Builder`:

```
@Builder
@Getter
public class Company {
    private long id;
    private String street;
    private String locationDescription;
    private String companyName;
    private String state;
    private String country;
    private String zipCode;
    
    public static Company parse(String line) {
        String[] arr = line.split(",");
        
        return Company.builder()
            .id(Long.parseLong(arr[0]))
            .locationDescription(arr[2])
            .companyName(arr[3])
            .state(arr[4])
            .country(arr[5])
            .zipCode(arr[6])
            .build();
    }
}
```

And that's how we can generate a list of Companies with unique `id`s:

```
List<String> sourceList = List.of(
    "123456,greenwitch street,near dominos store,Opp sandwitch company,Neyork,US,876890",
    "123480,Postwitch street,near KFC store,Opp masala company,Newyork,US,876891",
    "123456,Newyork street,near 100th avenue,King master company,Texas,US,10005"
);
    
List<Company> uniqueCompanies = sourceList.stream()
    .map(Company::parse)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Company::getId,       // keyMapper - generating a Key
        Function.identity(),  // valueMapper - creating a Value
        (left, right) -> left // mergeFunction - resolving duplicates
    ))
    .values().stream().toList();
```